# Proof explanation, if $a_n \leq c \text{ } \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ for $c \in \mathbb{R}$, then $a \leq c$ also holds

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-explanation

Let $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a convergent sequence with $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = a$.

Prove, if  $a_n \leq c \text{ } \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ for $c \in \mathbb{R}$, then $a \leq c$ also holds.

Can someone given an intuitive explanation of what is being asked for?

This is the proof:

> Assume $a_n \leq c \Rightarrow a -c < 0$. Since $a_n \to a$ there exists $\forall \epsilon  > 0$ an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ with $|a_n -a| < \epsilon$, especially for $\epsilon = a-c$
> $$\Rightarrow |a_n - a| < a-c \text{ } \forall n > N \\ 
> \Leftrightarrow - (a-c) < a_n - a < a-c \text{ } \forall n > N \\
> \Leftrightarrow c < a_n \forall n \in \mathbb{N} \text{ } \unicode{x21af}$$

I don't quite understand this proof by contradiction.

I also think it wouldn't work if $a_n < c \text{ } \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$.

For example, if we take $a_n = 1 - \frac{1}{n}, a_n < 1 \text{ } \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ but $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 1$.

Comment: This is called "principle of preservation of weak inequalities by passing to the limit"

Comment: "Can someone given an intuitive explanation of what is being asked for?" If a sequence is all $\leq c,$ then the limit can't be greater than $c.$

Comment: But you are correct, it isn't true if you replace $\leq$ everywhere with $<$.

Comment: "Assume $a_n\leq c\implies a-c<0.$" That is confusing and wrong. It should assume all $a_n\leq c$ **and** $a>c,$ (or, equivalently,  $a-c>0.$)

Comment: And, indeed, the proof later sets $\epsilon =a-c,$ so, since it is always assumed $\epsilon>0,$ the proof really should assume $a-c>0.$ Either an error in the proof or an error in your copying to the question.

Comment: Assume that at the point $c$ on the real line there is a high vertical wall. The points $a_n$ are all located on left hand side of the wall, but they can touch the wall. Any accumulation point of $a_n$ is also located on the left hand side of the wall.